# View for Taxonomy terms?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

How can I output nodes which linked with taxonomy term through a view?
How can I link taxonomy vocabulary with a view wich will output appropriate nodes for each term of this vocabulary?

In Drupal 7 we have two modules:

- [Taxonomy Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) (is not present in D8).
- [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) (is raw in D8).

Comment: TVI is now available in Beta for Drupal 8. It works well for me.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need additional modules to create different Taxonomy term pages, in D7 nor D8. Taxonomy Display and Taxonomy Views Integrator modules save steps in certain cases, but you can recreate their functionality with configuring different Views for different cases.

You can reuse the existing `Taxonomy term` Views (this lists nodes based on the taxonomy term in the URL).

If you need different Taxonomy page settings for each Vocabulary you can Duplicate the Taxonomy term Views (that shows Content tagged with a term) as many times as you have different Vocabularies, and add Filters to each to apply only to one Vocabulary.

Then you can also change all the other options related to how you want different Vocabulary terms Content to be displayed, because you'll have a different View for each Vocabulary.

Comment: How exactly the "Filters" should be configured? I created Contextual filter with this parameters: If value is not in URL - 404, Validator - Taxonomy term ID, Vocabulary - one specific on each view, Validate user has access to the Taxonomy term, Action to do if validation will not pass - 404.

Comment: @Bobík that sounds good. The `Validator` and `Vocabulary` are required in this case (under `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`), all other options you can set to your liking. Just make sure you don't set to accept multiple arguments, or that the option clash between different Views you've configured specifically for each Vocabulary.

Comment: Hmm, it still loads the view what was last saved (it behaves like configured by Action to do if validation will not pass).

Comment: @Bobík it's impossible to say flying blind. Maybe open a question with all the details?